# Get all immediate children and nothing deeper

Tags: xpath, webdriver

```
WebElement body = browser.findElement(By.xpath("//body"));

body.findElement(By.xpath("")); // I want to get all child elements 
                                // inside body, but nothing deeper.
```

Example document.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
    </div>
    <span>
      <table>
      </table>
    </span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Expected result is `div` and `span`. I have no controll over the documents and they vary greatly.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`("*")` gives all the child elements of the context node. So use:

```
body.findElement(By.xpath("*"));
```

Answer (score 11):

Here's another way to get the direct children of an element:

```
element.findElement(By.xpath("./*"));
```

Answer (score 7):

```
/html/body/*
```

Will select only immediate children elements of `body`.

Do remember that if you copy all these selected nodes, you also copy their content. So, if you do `copy-of`, `table` will also be produced to the resulting document.

Also, I would recommend to read at least XPath basics, you ask too many similar questions.

Comment: +1 Right answer. You wrote: *nodeset will contain their child elements also*. This is wrong or it isn't clear your thoughts. I think you could remove that without lost.

Comment: @Alejandro, yeah, that isn't a good formulation, can't word this properly. How would you say that?

Comment: Maybe you wanted to say something like: *Do remember that if you copy all this selected nodes, you are also copying theirs content.*

Comment: @Alejandro. Thanks. Edited the answer with your words.

Answer (score 3):

The [`child`](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp) instead of `descendant` may helps someone.